# Swift 2: Different gravity to different sprites

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game where i need to be able to change the speed of the player sprite. I think the best option is to effect the sprites by gravity. To give the user the feeling of movement I want the background to move in the exact same speed just in the opposite direction.

How can i give the background a different gravity then the player sprite?

If you know about a better approach I would really appreciate your suggestions as well.

Comment: you can apply the game camera to your player on the y axis.  so when the player jumps, the background scrolls down, and falling makes it go up

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `linearDamping` property of a node to change the rate that it falls. From the docs,

> This property is used to simulate fluid or air friction forces on the
>   body. The property must be a value between 0.0 and 1.0. The default
>   value is 0.1. If the value is 0.0, no linear damping is applied to the
>   object.

Note that linear damping will also affect the node's side-to-side movement as well.